# Taking next x values for each item in pandas column and making them into adjacent row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df:

```
    0           1    2     3     4  
0   44.000000   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0    
1   42.200001   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0        
2   44.799999   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0    
3   47.520000   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0
4   49.760000   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0
5   53.420000   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0
```

my expected output is to have (each element in columns, have next 3 values on a row):

```
    0           1            2           3      
0   44.000000   42.200001    44.799999   47.520000      
1   42.200001   44.799999    47.520000   49.760000          
2   44.799999   47.520000    49.760000   53.420000  
3   47.520000   etc.
4   49.760000   etc. 
5   53.420000
```

What I'm trying to do here is go fast (task is to get below certain speed) , I'm thinking if I create an empty df, and then use .apply(lambda: #fncineed, axis=1) it can improve performance much more. (rather than going through whole data index and applying fnc to moving window)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this if I understand your question correctly:

```
df.apply(lambda x: df['0'].shift(-df.columns.get_loc(x.name)))
```

Output:

```
           0          1          2      3      4
0  44.000000  42.200001  44.799999  47.52  49.76
1  42.200001  44.799999  47.520000  49.76  53.42
2  44.799999  47.520000  49.760000  53.42    NaN
3  47.520000  49.760000  53.420000    NaN    NaN
4  49.760000  53.420000        NaN    NaN    NaN
5  53.420000        NaN        NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: awesome, (and works about 100 times faster than using the loop I was)

Comment: Awesome sir well played with `get_loc` and `shift`

Comment: fyi, df.apply(lambda x: df[0].shift(-x.name))   works too

Comment: Yeah, with your column names as integers, but if you had strings for names, you'd need to use this more robust code.

Comment: @thomas.mac add one in case you have character columns name

Answer (score 1):

If you want each column `1-3` to contain the three values that follow column `0`, row-wise, you can use `shift()`:

```
n = 3
pd.concat([df.iloc[:,0], 
           df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: (df.iloc[:,0]
                                            .shift(-int(x.name))[:n])
                                            .iloc[:,:n]]), axis=1)

           0          1          2      3
0  44.000000  42.200001  44.799999  47.52
1  42.200001  44.799999  47.520000  49.76
2  44.799999  47.520000  49.760000  53.42
3  47.520000        NaN        NaN    NaN
4  49.760000        NaN        NaN    NaN
5  53.420000        NaN        NaN    NaN
```

This assumes you don't want to populate cols `1-3` if there aren't 3 values available.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this

```
new=pd.concat([df['0'].shift(-x) for x in list(range(df.shape[1]))],axis=1)
new.columns=df.columns
new
Out[178]: 
           0          1          2      3      4
0  44.000000  42.200001  44.799999  47.52  49.76
1  42.200001  44.799999  47.520000  49.76  53.42
2  44.799999  47.520000  49.760000  53.42    NaN
3  47.520000  49.760000  53.420000    NaN    NaN
4  49.760000  53.420000        NaN    NaN    NaN
5  53.420000        NaN        NaN    NaN    NaN
```